# What is up with Intel C++ Compiler std::filesystem support?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to port a project from VS2015 that used `std::experimental::filesystem` to use Intel C++ Compiler 19.1.

The compiler gets upset when attempting to deal with this:

```
#include <filesystem>
std::experimental::filesystem::path foo;
```

saying that it can't resolve the namespace `experimental`.
Ok, that is supposedly removed, so we'll try with just `std::filesystem`, as follows:

```
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::path foo;
```

Error: can not resolve namespace `filesystem`.
Let's try stepping backwards:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
std::experimental::filesystem::path foo;
```

Now it "works" but complains that the `<experimental/filesystem>` header is deprecated by Microsoft and will be removed, superseded by the C++17  header providing std::filesystem, and that I have to provide a `#define` acknowledging this to allow it to continue.

Here is the main part of the question:

Does anyone have any certainty on the state of Intel's C++ Compiler support for std::filesystem?

A question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782902/stdfilesystem-and-stdexperimentalfilesystem-problem-in-different-compilers) which asks about GCC, solutions seem to work there but similar will fail under Intel C++, or use workarounds I'm trying to avoid (see Edit subsection below).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990928/which-compilers-support-stdfilesystem) was asked back in 2016 and before the C++17 standard was ratified, and doesn't mention Intel C++.

The [C++ Compiler Support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page mentions "File system library", and says Intel Parallel STL support is "N/A", without mention of the Intel C++ compiler.

As for compiler settings, Intel C++ doesn't seem to offer a C++ Standard version as MSVC does.

### Edit

I'm trying to avoid using the `#define` to suppress the deprecation of experimental header. I have tried using some `#ifdef`s to selectively `#include` based on compiler, but _MSC_VER is defined somehow (1920) when I have the compiler set to Intel C++.

Comment: Did you set [`/Qstd=c++17`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-std-qstd)?

Comment: Did you try Intels [GET HELP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/support)?